# Pandas groupby not working with Wrong number of items passed 4, placement implies 1

Tags: pandas, group-by

So it seems that my gorupby does not work, when I try to input more parameters for the function that I try to apply with my groupby apply.

I have found something that looks like my scenario here: 
http://pbpython.com/weighted-average.html in the section **'Grouping Data with the Weighted Average'** around halfway down the article.

I try to use my function where 2 columns from the df is needed as parameters to do my calculation.

**My code**

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

text = """Ticker Date Adj_Close Volume MACD emaSlw emaFst MACDsig MACDperc
A 18-07-2016 46.8 1362900.0 0.55 45.81 45.26 0.21 -0.9954
A 19-07-2016 46.98 2579000.0 0.6 45.99 45.39 0.29 -0.9937
AA 18-07-2016 10.92 16297800.0 0.32 10.27 9.94 0.1 -0.99
AA 19-07-2016 10.63 14316200.0 0.33 10.32 9.99 0.15 -0.9856
AAL 18-07-2016 36.03 8604200.0 1.15 32.84 31.69 -0.08 -10.023
AAL 19-07-2016 36.01 7928100.0 1.32 33.33 32.01 0.19 -0.9942
AAP 18-07-2016 164.4 516800.0 2.83 162.59 159.75 2.72 -0.9832
AAP 19-07-2016 163.7 854700.0 2.71 162.76 160.05 2.76 -0.983
AAPL 18-07-2016 99.83 36439900.0 0.5 97.36 96.86 -0.16 -10.017
AAPL 19-07-2016 99.87 23703900.0 0.67 97.75 97.08 -0.01 -10.001
ABBV 18-07-2016 63.56 6384800.0 0.9 63.06 62.16 0.71 -0.9887
ABBV 19-07-2016 63.32 5716800.0 0.86 63.1 62.25 0.78 -0.9876
ABC 18-07-2016 86.03 1113600.0 2.31 82.91 80.6 1.52 -0.9817
ABC 19-07-2016 85.92 1975400.0 2.38 83.38 81.0 1.7 -0.9796
ABT 18-07-2016 42.09 7524200.0 1.05 41.14 40.09 0.75 -0.9818
ABT 19-07-2016 41.8 8395400.0 1.02 41.24 40.22 0.84 -0.9796"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text), delim_whitespace=1, parse_dates=[0], index_col=1)

df.drop(['Volume', 'emaSlw', 'emaFst'],inplace=True,axis=1)

def Trade_signal_calc(group):

    if df['MACD'].irow(-1) > 0: # MACD is pos. so trade (BUY/Sell)
        # BUY signals
        # if todays MACD is higher than signal, AND yesturday's MACD was lower than signal
        if  (df['MACD'].irow(-1) > df['MACDsig'].irow(-1)) \
        & (df['MACD'].irow(-2) < df['MACDsig'].irow(-2)) :
            df['Trade'] = 'Buy'
            return df
        # SELL signals
        # if todays MACD is lower than signal, AND yesturday's MACD was higher than signal - reverse the above
        elif  (df['MACD'].irow(-1) < df['MACDsig'].irow(-1)) \
        & ((df['MACD'].irow(-2)) > df['MACDsig'].irow(-2)) : 
            df['Trade'] = 'Sell'
            return df
        else:   # No strong Buy or Sell signals
            return df
    else:   # MACD is neg. so don't trade
        return df


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Multiindex Needed for my groupby to work properly ???
    df = df.set_index('Ticker', append=True)
    print ('\ndf \n%s\n---------------------------------\nMultiindex df\n%s' %(df.iloc[0:4,0:6], df.iloc[0:4,0:6]))    

    df['Trade'] = df.groupby(level='Ticker')[['MACD','MACDsig']].apply(Trade_signal_calc)
    print ('\ndf with Buy & Sell signals \ndfTrade shows trades from MACD & MACDsig comparison (summary from df) (Output)\n%s\nSignals: \nBuy: (df(MACD[-1]) > df(MACDsig[-1])) & (df(MACD[-2]) < df(MACDsig[-2])) \nSell: (df(MACD[-1]) < df(MACDsig[-1])) & (df(MACD[-2]) > df(MACDsig[-2])) \n\n%s' %(75*'-',df[['Trade','MACD','MACDsig','Adj_Close','Date']]))
    # Resetting index from before doing groupby w. multi-index
    df = df.reset_index('Ticker')    

    # Test the first 3 rows of each group for 'Difference' col transgress groups...
    df = df.groupby('Ticker').head(3).reset_index().set_index('Date')
    print ('\ndf (summary from df) (Output)\n',df,'\n')
```

But when I try to apply it in my code I get an error.

```
df 
                   Adj_Close  MACD  MACDsig  MACDperc
Date       Ticker                                    
18-07-2016 A           46.80  0.55     0.21   -0.9954
19-07-2016 A           46.98  0.60     0.29   -0.9937
18-07-2016 AA          10.92  0.32     0.10   -0.9900
19-07-2016 AA          10.63  0.33     0.15   -0.9856
---------------------------------
Multiindex df
                   Adj_Close  MACD  MACDsig  MACDperc
Date       Ticker                                    
18-07-2016 A           46.80  0.55     0.21   -0.9954
19-07-2016 A           46.98  0.60     0.29   -0.9937
18-07-2016 AA          10.92  0.32     0.10   -0.9900
19-07-2016 AA          10.63  0.33     0.15   -0.9856
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-27-d88b1f547887>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/Morten/Documents/Design/Python/CrystalBall - Local - Git/Git - CrystalBall/sandbox/test_groupby_multiple_Input_Cols.py', wdir='C:/Users/Morten/Documents/Design/Python/CrystalBall - Local - Git/Git - CrystalBall/sandbox')

  File "C:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-3.3.5.7_2ndInst\python-3.3.5.amd64\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 682, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-3.3.5.7_2ndInst\python-3.3.5.amd64\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 85, in execfile
    exec(compile(open(filename, 'rb').read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/Morten/Documents/Design/Python/CrystalBall - Local - Git/Git - CrystalBall/sandbox/test_groupby_multiple_Input_Cols.py", line 63, in <module>
    df['Trade'] = df.groupby(level='Ticker')[['MACD','MACDsig']].apply(Trade_signal_calc)

  File "C:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-3.3.5.7_2ndInst\python-3.3.5.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2117, in __setitem__
    self._set_item(key, value)

  File "C:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-3.3.5.7_2ndInst\python-3.3.5.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2195, in _set_item
    NDFrame._set_item(self, key, value)

  File "C:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-3.3.5.7_2ndInst\python-3.3.5.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1190, in _set_item
    self._data.set(key, value)

  File "C:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-3.3.5.7_2ndInst\python-3.3.5.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 2975, in set
    self.insert(len(self.items), item, value)

  File "C:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-3.3.5.7_2ndInst\python-3.3.5.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 3074, in insert
    placement=slice(loc, loc+1))

  File "C:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-3.3.5.7_2ndInst\python-3.3.5.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 2093, in make_block
    placement=placement)

  File "C:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-3.3.5.7_2ndInst\python-3.3.5.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 77, in __init__
    len(self.values), len(self.mgr_locs)))

ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 4, placement implies 1
```

It seems like a parameter error, but I don't use any params other than the groupby object 'group' in the Trade_signal_calc(group) call.

In my code I have corrected the error that EdChum pointed out. Thanks Ed.

Does anyone have any idea as to what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add additional `[]` around your column selection:

```
 df['Trade'] = df.groupby(level=1)[['MACD','MACDsig']].apply(Trade_signal_calc, 'MACD','MACDsig')
```

The error is telling you that no key exists as it's treating your selection as a tuple, this is no different to doing:

```
df['Trade'] = df['MACD','MACDsig'].groupby(level=1).apply(Trade_signal_calc, 'MACD','MACDsig')
```

if you look at the syntax this way you can see why it fails so you need to add additional `[]` so that it becomes a list of columns

Comment: Thanks Ed, Now I get another error about pandas 'DataFrame' object not callable... Se my question update.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing but the problem here is that you've defined a function which is operating directly on the df whilst you're trying to operate group-wise. I think you need to look at what you want and what that function is doing and consider whether it's what you want as this is why the error is being raised

Comment: I need to calculate a new column 'Trades' in my pandas. I am using the function 'Trade_signal_calc'. And to avoid mixing numbers from the different groups I use pd groupby. So I think it cannot be done any simpler than this. I am puzzled however that I cannot get access to the df columns in question in each group. Like so: df('MACD'[-1]) (for last row), df('MACD'[-2]) (for second-last row)...
And The function does work on group, like I specify in the parameters of the f(). The first par. is 'group'

Comment: I'd concentrate on separating the code out and make it simple to build it up at the moment I don't have time to debug this for you